# Java library to convert "X-Document-Type: Workbook" to Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, apache-tika, webarchive

We have some legacy data in `.xls` (HSSF) format that we are converting to `.xlsx` (XSSF) format using Apache POI library.  It was all working very well till we started seeing many  `org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException`.  Upon closer examination we realized that the files that are throwing this exception are not actually Excel files (despite the misleading `.xls` extension) but Single File Web Page files (web archive `X-Document-Type: Workbook`).

---

**Question)** Is there any opensource Java library that converts "X-Document-Type: Workbook" to Excel?

---

**Addendum**: Clarification, as sought by @kiwiwings

No the files are not "XML Workbook" format.  They are MIME documents with the `X-Document-Type: Workbook` declaration.  Each part is a standard HTML file, with its own table.

The files are given the `.xls` extension and Excel is able to open them, albeit after issuing the following warning:

> *The file you are trying to open, 'blah-blah-blah.xls', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?*

Comment: I think that's one of the ones that Apache Tika handles, so you could use Tika to generate an XHTML table of the contents, then one of a number of libraries to get the contents from the XHTML, and finally Apache POI to generate the XLSX

Comment: are those files in the "[XML Workbook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats#Excel_XML_Spreadsheet_example)" format?